# Contentful graphql api not fetching localized `linkedfrom` items

Tags: graphql, contentful, contentful-api

Basically I want to get localized values for the entries linking to my unique entry.

```
movie(id: $movieId) {
  linkedFrom {
    spanishMovieLocations: movieLocationCollection(locale: "es-ES") { 
      items {//fields with localized values} 
    }
  }
}
```

But instead I get no results in my collection array.  Querying directly for `movieLocationCollection(locale: "es-ES")` gets me localized values and has some matching `movie.sys.id` that is used in `$movieId`.

This works fine, but then I dont get the localized fields I need.

```
movie(id: $movieId) {
  linkedFrom {
    movieLocationCollection { 
      items {//fields with non-localized values} 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having this same issue, did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 3):

from the contentful site:

> We ... made the querying of localized reference content easier by introducing a new allowedLocales argument.

https://www.contentful.com/blog/2020/12/03/three-new-graphql-features-2020/

```
movie(id: $movieId) {
  linkedFrom(allowedLocales: ["es-ES"]) {
    movieLocationCollection { 
      items {//fields with non-localized values} 
    }
  }
}
```

In my project I had to include both locales

```
query ($parner: String) { 
  partnerCollection(limit: 1, locale: "fr-CA", where: {title: $parner}) {
    items {
      title
      sys {
        id
      }
      linkedFrom(allowedLocales: ["en-US", "fr-CA"]) {
        benefitCollection(limit: 3) {
          total
          items {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```